# Enable / Disable video cards from Window 7 64-bit via Python

Tags: python, windows-7, wmi, pci

I have a 64-bit Windows 7 machine with 2 PCIe video cards, one of which I would like to be able to programmatically enable and disable ideally from a Python script. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a MS tool called DevCon, part of the WDK tool kit that can be downloaded as part of a 640 MB ISO from here...

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=11800

Documentation can be found at...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg487458

This installs 3 copies of the devcon app in C:\WinDDK\7600.16385.1\tools\devcon\

```
amd64/devcon.exe : Win7 64-bit
i386/devcon.exe  : WinXP / Win7 32-bit 
ia64/devcon.exe  : Itanium 64-bit processor
```

Each DevCon itself is only ~70kB and needs to be run as administrator from the command line (In Windows-7 right click on cmd.exe / run as administor).

From this tool you can find the status of, enable and disable devices

e.g. from the dos prompt

```
> devcon resources =display            // show list of display adapters
> devcon status xxxx                   // show status of adapter xxxx 
> devcon disable xxxx                  // disable adapter xxx
```